# How to use "$" in SQL plus?

Tags: linux, database, suse

I'm facing the following problem.

When I try to execute the following command in sqlplus in my SLES:

```
sqlplus -S user/password@balancer.domain.cl <<EOF
SELECT INSTANCE_NUMBER, HOST_NAME, STARTUP_TIME, STATUS, DATABASE_STATUS, BLOCKED 
FROM GV$INSTANCE;
EOF
```

it shows me the following error:

```
SQL> SELECT INSTANCE_NUMBER, HOST_NAME, STARTUP_TIME, STATUS, DATABASE_STATUS, BLOCKED FROM GVINSTANCE
                                                                                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I suppose it is because in the query is "$" involved but I am not sure.

Is there a way to run that command in sqlplus client using Linux as the OS?

If I am doing something wrong please point me in the right direction.

---

**Enviroment Details.**

- O.S = SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3
- Oracle Instant Client = Release 12.1.0.2.0
- SQLPLUS =  SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one problem is your shell syntax:

```
sqlplus -S user/password@balancer.domain.cl <<EOF
SELECT INSTANCE_NUMBER, HOST_NAME, STARTUP_TIME, STATUS, DATABASE_STATUS, BLOCKED 
FROM GV$INSTANCE;
EOF
```

That is referred to as a "here-document", and *shell variables* (names prefixed with `$`) are normally expanded.  To prevent the expansion, **quote** the first use of `EOF`, e.g.,

```
sqlplus -S user/password@balancer.domain.cl <<"EOF"
SELECT INSTANCE_NUMBER, HOST_NAME, STARTUP_TIME, STATUS, DATABASE_STATUS, BLOCKED 
FROM GV$INSTANCE;
EOF
```

Another problem may be the special character in the table name.  You can quote that as well (telling Oracle to ignore some of the syntax rules it uses for SQL).  The improvement would look like this:

```
sqlplus -S user/password@balancer.domain.cl <<"EOF"
SELECT INSTANCE_NUMBER, HOST_NAME, STARTUP_TIME, STATUS, DATABASE_STATUS, BLOCKED 
FROM "GV$INSTANCE";
EOF
```

Further reading:

- [How to print “$” in here-document](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68419/how-to-print-in-here-document)
- [Oracle: What exactly do quotation marks around the table name do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563090/oracle-what-exactly-do-quotation-marks-around-the-table-name-do)

Comment: Ty for your fast and complete answer, ill test it tomorrow.

Comment: Works like a charm. very ty for the orientation, i hope it could help others to fix the syntax.